# Uncaught Error: new Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: angularjs, firebase

In an AngularJS app, I'm trying to get a firebase reference that does exist and I'm following the suggestions of a similar question here.

Now, I've identified the following line in my controller as the culprit:

```
var indexRef = new Firebase(refString);
```

it is nestled in a setTimeout() since that seemed to solve another error of undefined. I currently have

```
refString.replace(/\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\| ]/g, '');
```

in order to avoid

> Uncaught Error: new Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".

Here's an instance running live on [Heroku](https://masuk-additions.herokuapp.com/#/) and here's the [plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/G43dqi8H4dn6d8oXdvyy)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to replace forward slashes in a url. By the way, you should try to figure out what a regex character class is.

You should have used console.log() to display the result of the replace() to see the url you are actually using for firebase:

```
var refString = 'https://path/to' + '/index/domains/' + 'other/stuff';
console.log(refString.replace(/\//g, ''));

--output:--
https:somethinghereindexdomainsotherstuff
```

That url won't work on teh internets.  You have to know basic javascript, as well as basic javascript debugging, *before* trying to learn angular or firebase.

Comment: Good help to the following answer: 
`var refString = baseURL+'index/domains/'+ location.replace(/\./g, '-');`

I accept your high and mighty condescension with much gratitude. I overlooked to check the log because the same code works in my dev environment and this is a common issue dealing with denormalized db practices.

In anycase, you're correct. good eye on the regex. Still getting an error on the plunk but heroku is now loading properly, as well as gh-pages.

thanks again, i'll hit up codecademy and code school along with flash cards for regex character classes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to parse refString with the regex, but to parse location instead.

```
var refString = baseURL+'/index/domains/'+ location.replace(/\./g, '-');
console.log('refString',refString);
```

output: `refString https://tezt.firebaseio.com/index/domains/run-plnkr-co`

refString = a db id on the path https://tezt.firebaseio.com/domains hence the need to parse the host before saving as a db key.